# Splitting Numpy array based on value

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have this NumPy array:

```
a = np.array([0, 3, 5, 5, 0, 10, 14, 15, 56, 0, 12, 23, 45, 23, 12, 45, 
              0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0 ,0])
```

I would like to print all the numbers between 0s and automatically add them to a new `np.array` (see below):

```
a1=[3, 5, 5]
a2=[10, 14, 15, 56]
a3=[12, 23, 45, 23, 12, 45]
a4=[1]
a5=[2, 3, 4]
```

Is there a built-in function to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `groupby()` function from `itertools`, and specify the `key` as the boolean condition of zero or nonzero. In such a way, all consecutive zeros and nonzeros will be grouped together. Use `if` filter to pick up groups of nonzeros and use `list` to convert the non zero groupers to lists.

```
from itertools import groupby
[list(g) for k, g in groupby(a, lambda x: x != 0) if k]

# [[3, 5], [10, 14, 15, 56], [12, 23, 45, 23, 12, 45], [1], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`np.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) -

```
idx = np.where(a!=0)[0]
aout = np.split(a[idx],np.where(np.diff(idx)!=1)[0]+1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [23]: a
Out[23]: 
array([ 0,  3,  5,  5,  0, 10, 14, 15, 56,  0,  0,  0, 12, 23, 45, 23, 12,
       45,  0,  1,  0,  2,  3,  4,  0,  0,  0])

In [24]: idx = np.where(a!=0)[0]

In [25]: np.split(a[idx],np.where(np.diff(idx)!=1)[0]+1)
Out[25]: 
[array([3, 5, 5]),
 array([10, 14, 15, 56]),
 array([12, 23, 45, 23, 12, 45]),
 array([1]),
 array([2, 3, 4])]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the indices of zeros with np.where:

```
zeros = np.where(a == 0)[0]
```

And iterate over every pair to slice the array:

```
[a[i+1:j] for i, j in zip(zeros, zeros[1:]) if len(a[i+1:j])>0]

Out[46]: 
[array([3, 5]),
 array([10, 14, 15, 56]),
 array([12, 23, 45, 23, 12, 45]),
 array([1]),
 array([2, 3, 4])]
```

Comment: This solution does not work if the array starts with a non-zero integer, e.g. `a = np.array([1, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0, 10, 0])`

Comment: @Alexander It outputs `[3, 5]` and `[10]`. Isn't this correct?

Comment: With the sample I gave above, it should be [[1], [3, 5], [10]]

Comment: @Alexander Shouldn't 1 have 0 on the left side of it to be considered between zeros?

Comment: Fair enough.  Your answer is appears to solve what the OP has requested (although the question could be interpreted as splitting the array on zeros).

Comment: @Alexander I may have taken it too literal. Splitting actually makes more sense. Let me wait OP to weigh in. Psidom's answer is more elegant anyway. :)

Answer (score 3):

NumPy's `split()` and `where()` in a list compehension:

```
[x[x!=0] for x in np.split(a, np.where(a==0)[0]) if len(x[x!=0])]

[array([3, 5, 5]),
 array([10, 14, 15, 56]),
 array([12, 23, 45, 23, 12, 45]),
 array([1]),
 array([2, 3, 4])]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for numpy, this lambda function works on a list, but we can convert your numpy array to and from a list on the way in and out:

```
cut = lambda x: [j for j in [cut(x[:x.index(0)])]+cut(x[x.index(0)+1:]) if j] if x.count(0) else x

numpy.array(cut(list(a)))

# array([[3, 5, 5], [10, 14, 15, 56], [12, 23, 45, 23, 12, 45], [1], [2, 3, 4]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the worst way to do this, but you could also convert your array into a string and then split that string a couple  times:

```
long_string = "_".join(a.astype(str))

while long_string.startswith("0_"):
    long_string = long_string.removeprefix("0_")
while long_string.endswith("_0"):
    long_string = long_string.removesuffix("_0")

result = [list(map(int, i.split("_"))) for i in long_string.split("_0_")]

# result: [[3, 5, 5], [10, 14, 15, 56], [12, 23, 45, 23, 12, 45], [1], [2, 3, 4]]
```

You would need Python 3.9 for `.removeprefix()` and `.removesuffix()`.